# ElasticSearch - Error while querying AWS ElasticSearch Service - Unsupported Content-Type: text/html

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch HighLevel Rest Client, I am trying to search the [AWS ElasticSearch service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) which has data I reindexed before. The search code is

```
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(quickSearchDTO.getIndexName()); 
    searchRequest.types(type);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
    searchSourceBuilder.size(quickSearchDTO.getHitsPerPage());
    QueryBuilder query = quickSearchDTO.getQuery(type, false); // Simple query
    searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
    searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    try { 
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
        buildSearchHits(quickSearchDTO, type, searchResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NSFException("Error while searching type : " + type , e);
    }
```

But, it is not providing results and it gives me the below error.

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Unable to parse response body
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:538) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:441) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:414) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:355) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at com.kar.demo.search.engine.ElasticSearchEngine.singleTypeSearch(ElasticSearchEngine.java:226) ~[classes/:?]
at com.kar.demo.search.engine.ElasticSearchEngine.search(ElasticSearchEngine.java:212) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy378.search(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.kar.demo.business.QuickSearchManagerImpl.quickSearch(QuickSearchManagerImpl.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379.quickSearch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.kar.demo.service.rest.QuickSearchController.quickSearch(QuickSearchController.java:95) [classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.kar.demo.security.AuthenticationTokenFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:114) [classes/:?]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:245) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_101]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:555) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:534) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:441) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:414) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:355) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at com.kar.demo.search.engine.ElasticSearchEngine.singleTypeSearch(ElasticSearchEngine.java:226) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.kar.demo.search.engine.ElasticSearchEngine.search(ElasticSearchEngine.java:212) ~[classes/:?]
```

Please check the Suppressed error above. I am getting a html in the error log as this - 
[html error of the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyKK1.png)
and this is followed by

```
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:355) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:344) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:437) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:327) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
... 1 more
```

I am getting this error only when I querying the AWS ES service only. When I try to query my local ElasticSearch instance, it works as expected, not throwing any error.

---

**Updated:**

AWS ES Service version : 6.0.1

ElasticSearch HighLevel Rest Client version - 6.0.1

Comment: Can you upgrade the client to 6.1.2?

Comment: No, I can't. If we upgrade to Rest Client version to 6.1.2, it gives me Connection exception. AWS ES supports only till v6.0

Comment: Interesting. I thought that the REST Client was supposed to work with any minor version. (BTW you should move to cloud.elastic.co). It sounds like the  Content-Type is not passed to the request which might have been fixed in later version (can't recall). Could you share the error message with 6.1.2?